# Why is my delete procedure not working the second time I invoke it?

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote the following codes to insert new sheets, rename them and delete them.
But when I call the delete sub for the second time, it won't work because the NumSheets goes to zero and even though there are more than 2 sheets.

```
Public NumSheets As Integer
Sub NewCCSheet()
    Dim n As Integer

    n = InputBox("How many 16-24 Vehicle C.C.sheets do you need? (Enter a number only)")

    NewVehicle (n)
End Sub
Function NewVehicle(n As Integer)
    For i = 1 To n
        NumSheets = NumSheets + 1
        Worksheets("16-24 Vehicle C.C.1").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Ave. Vehicle C.C.")
        ActiveSheet.Name = "16-24 Vehicle C.C." & CStr(NumSheets + 1)
        Range("B5").ClearContents
        Range("D4").ClearContents
        Range("E12:E13").ClearContents
        Range("B15:E23").ClearContents
        MsgBox NumSheets
    Next i
End Function
Sub DeleteSheets()
    MsgBox NumSheets
    Dim Ans As String
    If NumSheets = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can't delete 16-24 Vehicle C.C.1 Worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Ans = MsgBox("Delete current worksheet?", vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbYes Then
        NumSheets = NumSheets - 1
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MsgBox NumSheets
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why my codes are formatted this way on the screen.....It is hard to understand.....

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases where your code may subtract 1 from `NumSheets` without deleting a sheet -- for instance, I don't believe it'd delete the last sheet from the workbook if there's only 1 left. The `On Error Resume Next` opens up potential for other errors to cause mismatches between `NumSheets` and the actual number of sheets, too.

Would you be able to use `Sheets().Count` instead of `NumSheets`? If so, that'd give you an up-to-date, accurate count of the actual number of sheets at a given time, and you wouldn't have to mess with tracking the number of them yourself. So your code could look like:

```
Sub NewCCSheet()
    Dim n As Integer

    n = InputBox("How many 16-24 Vehicle C.C.sheets do you need? (Enter a number only)")

    NewVehicle (n)
End Sub

Function NewVehicle(n As Integer)
    For i = 1 To n
        Worksheets("16-24 Vehicle C.C.1").Copy Before:=Worksheets("Ave. Vehicle C.C.")
        ActiveSheet.Name = "16-24 Vehicle C.C." & CStr(Sheets().Count + 1)
        Range("B5").ClearContents
        Range("D4").ClearContents
        Range("E12:E13").ClearContents
        Range("B15:E23").ClearContents
    Next i
End Function

Sub DeleteSheets()
    Dim Ans As String
    If Sheets().Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You can't delete 16-24 Vehicle C.C.1 Worksheet"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Ans = MsgBox("Delete current worksheet?", vbYesNo)
    If Ans = vbYes Then
        On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I want to have  a specific variable to keep track of certain sheets I created. I could take out On Error Resume Next statement. But Excel gives me Automation Error and I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Also, I realize the value of NumSheets goes to zero after it finished going through the module. How do you preserve the value of a variable in vba??